# Melhor forma de recuperar dados para um Datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework-6, nfe

Qual a melhor forma de recuperar os dados de uma tabela direto para um DataGridView ?

Estou com várias dúvidas, pois, muita gente não recomenda usar UnitOfWork o que facilita bastante e deixa o código bem mais limpo.

```
    var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(new DBConecta());
    var _registros = unitOfWork.RepoPaises.Get();
    BindingListView<CNAES> _DataView = new BindingListView<CNAES>(_registros);
    dbGride.DataSource = _DataView;
```

Após ver aqui no forum pessoas dizendo que não faz sentido usar UoW, já que o Entity Framework já é a camada de acesso, voltei para o modo normal, mas estou achando tudo muito estranho

```
        _context = new DBConecta();

        var registros = _context.CNAES.
            Select(c => new
            {
                id = c.id,
                nome = c.nome,
                ativo = c.ativo,
                usuarioNome = c.usuario.primeiro_nome + " " + c.usuario.segundo_nome,
                created_at = c.created_at,
                updated_at = c.updated_at,
                usuario_id = c.usuario_id
            }).ToList();


        this.dbGride.DataSource = registros;
        AfterRetrieve();
        _context.Dispose();
```

Como nunca trabalhei em equipes de .NET não sei quais as melhores práticas, gostaria de uma orientação. Obrigado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Com essa quantidade de dados a melhor forma mesmo é o Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Da maneira que você fez não está errado.

Como sugestão, na sua entidade CNAES vc poderia criar uma propriedade chamada usuarioNome que retorna o nome e o sobrenome

```
public usuarioNome
{
    get {
        if (usuario == null) return "";
        return usuario.primeiro_nome + " " + usuario.segundo_nome
    }
}
```

Assim vc pode simplificar seu código para popular seu combo `dbGride.DataSource = _context.CNAES.ToList();`

Uma boa prática seria também fazer a paginação dos seus dados utilizando os metodos Take e Skip

```
dbGride.DataSource = _context.CNAES.Skip(100).Take(50).ToList();
```

Comment: De fato, eu já fazia isto, mas isto gera um problema, o DataGridView fica executando este Get a todo momento.

Comment: Paulo, outro problema é que desta maneira, todos os campos da tabela de usuários são recuperados http://pastebin.com/ybkSDgzz

Comment: @duardbr não está errado executar esse get para cada linha... é assim mesmo pois é um campo "calculado" e vc mantém a regra no seu domínio...

Comment: o problema, é que este select traz também TODOS CAMPOS da tabela de usuário, sendo que eu queria somente o nome calculado.

Answer (score 0):

Bom pessoal, o melhor modo de fazer este select, envolvendo uma entidade e a tabela de usuários (para buscar o usuário que trabalhou por último no registro) que eu encontrei, foi este :

```
    protected override void Retrieve()
    {
        base.Retrieve();
        _context = new DBConecta(this.strConecta);

        var _query = from r in _context.CNAES
                     from u in _context.Usuarios
                     where u.id == r.usuario_id
                     select new { r.id, r.nome, r.ativo, r.created_at, r.updated_at, r.usuario_id, usuarioNome = r.usuario.login };

        dbGride.DataSource = _query.ToList();
        AfterRetrieve();
    }
```

Fazendo assim, ele não traz todos os campos da tabela de usuários e sim apenas o campo que eu pedi. Isto é muito importante visto que uma tabela grande, trazer todos os dados de outra tabela referenciada pode ter um custo !

```
SELECT
```

`Extent1`.`id`, 
`Extent1`.`nome`, 
`Extent1`.`ativo`, 
`Extent1`.`created_at`, 
`Extent1`.`updated_at`, 
`Extent1`.`usuario_id`, 
`Extent2`.`primeiro_nome`
FROM `cnaes` AS `Extent1` INNER JOIN `Usuarios` AS `Extent2` ON `Extent1`.`usuario_id` = `Extent2`.`id`
-- Executing at 13/03/2016 16:54:36 -03:00
-- Completed in 0 ms with result: EFMySqlDataReader

Para mim esta foi a melhor solução.